# How do I make the connection for 2 lights with a power source between them?

Tags: wiring

I have 2 sensor activated lights with the power source in between the two lights. It is run with 14/3 romex wire from each light source to the power source. How do I make the connection?

Comment: What is the question? What is run with the existing wiring? What is wrong with the existing wiring?

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish: either sensor controlling both lights, one controlling both, or independent sensor control? Is the switch is supposed to power both?

Comment: Are you sure it's 14/3 and not 14/2 with ground? Remember the grounding conductor (usually bare) does not count toward the number of conductors.

Comment: There is not enough information here for anybody to answer this question.  Please consider adding additional details, and/or a diagram of the wiring.

Comment: the two lights i have have motion detection capability so that when someone walks by the lights turn on automatically. the wires that are run from the fixtures to a box that contains the power both lights have a black, red, white and ground. the box used to have a couple of relays in it so that when 1 motion sensor was activated both lights came on at the same time. it has never worked properly so i decided to have them work independently from one another. i connected the reds together and then when I went to connect the whites together, it sparked. should i connect the blacks together first?

Comment: You shouldn't be working on it when it is live.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that BOTH sensor-lights are identical with each having their own sensor. And therefore will work independently

You won't need to mess with the third (red) wires. Use what's called a "parallel" connection: Wire-nut the blacks together going to each fixture, Then wire-nut the Whites together. Then the Grounds together. After that, connect the two Blacks to the black lead at the source, then the two Whites to the white lead at the source, lastly the Grounds to the grounds at the source.

If you don't mind me saying, this is a very basic-type of thing to do. Might I suggest you get a good DIY book at the home-store before you do anything fancy, so you and your home are really safe?

Good Luck!